# Is my SDK Google Mobile Ads anterior to 7.0.0

Tags: android, mobile, sdk

please,
 is my SDK Google Mobile Ads vesion superior to 7.0.0 ?

here is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here: https://source.android.com/setup/build-numbers

> Nougat    7.0 API level 24

So your sdk (23) isn't greater than the version 7.0 (24)